# How do you get the list data from a wxpyton gui click event?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a list ctrl box and I populate it with data.

```
self.listView1.Append([sFilename,sTitle,sArtist,sAlbum,sDestDir])
```

I created an event that triggers when a user clicks on a specific item in the list

```
def OnListView1ListItemSelected(self, event):
    print "onListViewSelect"
```

This works, but what I am stuck on is how do I capture the single line of data from the list the user clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using wxPython 2.8.10, this is one way to drop the text from all columns in the selected row into a list.  You're getting the object, selected index, number of columns, and then grabbing the text from each column:

```
def onListView1ListItemSelected(self, event):
    obj     = event.GetEventObject()
    index   = event.GetIndex()
    columns = obj.GetColumnCount()
    data    = []

    for i in range(columns):
        item = obj.GetItem(index, i)
        data.append(item.GetText())

    print(data)
```

I mentioned the version because I think the newest wxPython release allows you to specify a column in wx.ListCtrl.GetItemText, which could simplify things a bit.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for and I will use it in the short term.  But I think I prefer the answer provided by @Mike Driscoll for a longer term and better implementation.

Comment: I agree with Mike on that.  It doesn't matter so much if you're just filling the list once and then retrieving items, but if you want to manipulate the data in any way, the ListCtrl on its own would be a pretty awkward way of storing it.

Comment: @robots.jpg - your answer worked initially, but when I tired to pull out a sinble value as a string it reads that it actually assigned a textual reference to the string.  I tried sTitle = obj.GetItem(index,2)  since I knew that the 2nd colum was the title of the song.  But when I try to 'print sTitle' I get:  (wx._controls.ListItem; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxListItem *' at 0x381d190

Comment: You're trying to print a ListItem.  Try the result of sTitle.GetText() instead.

Comment: @robots.jpg can you help me out a little more - im very new to this and im doing this as a self learning exercise.  I tired sTitle = obj.getText(index,2) and that failed with a 'no attribute of gettext'.  Then I tried a sTitle.GetText(obj.GetItem(index,2)) and in this case it failed because sTitle was not defined as an object of any type so it couldn't figure it out.  What I want is to read the vaule of the 2nd column and put it into a simple variable.  Tks again for the help

Comment: Look at it this way - you have to get the ListItem from the list, and then get the text from the ListItem. list_item=obj.GetItem(index,2) ... text=item.GetText().

Comment: I gotcha now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I spent way too long looking for this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to just associate the data with the row. You can read about my approach here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/

Personally, I like ObjectListView the best: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/index.html

Comment: The other answer was what I was looking for - however I like your blog post and I think I will use that to push me in a couple of different directions.  Thank you.